# displaying another html content in div on ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

**gameLike.jsp**

```
<div id="gameLikeStatus">
<a  href="likeit"   id="likeitlink">likeit</a>  
</div>

var dataString = 'elementId='+ '<s:property value="id"/>'+ '&elementType=' + 'games';                          

$(document).ready(function(){                                   
    $('a#likeitlink').bind('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({   
            type: "POST",   
            url: "likeit", 
            dataType: "text html",
            data: dataString,   
            success: function() {  
                $.post('isLiked',dataString, function(data) {
                    alert(data);//1
                    $('#gameLikeStatus').html(data);
                });

            }   
        }); 
    });

});
```

in `second.jsp` contains a link

```
<a  href="unlikeit"   id="Unlikeitlink">likeit</a>
```

Here I am liking the element and after like it should display

```
<a  href="unlikeit"   id="Unlikeitlink">likeit</a>
```

instead of

```
<a  href="likeit"   id="likeitlink">likeit</a>
```

at

```
<div id="gameLikeStatus"></div>
```

in `gameLike.jsp`, `alert(data);//1` is showing

```
<a  href="unlikeit"   id="Unlikeitlink">likeit</a>
```

this data but

```
$('#gameLikeStatus').html(data);
```

showing nothing.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Check your `</div` whether you close the end tag properly, or it is a typo in the question.

Comment: why your are using post inside ajax

Comment: @rajeshkakawat isLiked is a url which checking the status of user like and fatchin true if user like it or false if user unlike it. Can you tell me on success how can i call a url

Comment: @Manish than what likeit url do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
 $('.gameLikeStatus').html(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if ajax call is working or not cause i am not sure it work or not cause in anchor link u have defined **class = likeitlink**  where in jquery function u have used anchor link which is having **id = likeitlink**

second just use html as ajax dataType it always work for me.

Third you have used **class = gameLikeStatus** but when you have response from ajax success you have used **id=gameLikeStatus** that must be **$(.gameLikeStatus)**

Comment: Please see again there was mistake every thing is id

Comment: does page contain more than one dom having same ID.?

Comment: you can also use firebug for firefox to see what response you got after ajax call.
Also u have called $.post inside of jquery ajax call i dont know why its needed.
But there must be problem in either DOM ID or in second time ajax call response.
use firebug to see it with all data including headers and params and all...

Comment: after success i an callong another url with given data string so i used post. Is it wrong

Comment: no its not wrong. but as i said check ajax and post call response in firebug problem must be there otherwise code is perfect nothin is wrong in it..use that tool to see it in action.

Comment: check datastring too in firebug.
see what parameter you pass to ur ajax call.
u can also get value of dom element using <b>jQuery("DOM").attr('value');</b>

Comment: One more thing please add success : function (data).
u forgot to pass response as argument in success callback.

Answer (score 0):

The div has an id, so use $("#gameLikeStatus").append(data);